# When trying to run a Django project I get the NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, python-2.7, web-applications, django-views

I am trying to run this project on local server and I get the follwoing error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

My url file is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^courses/', include('courses.urls', namespace='courses')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And this is the views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

This is the setting file

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&s5%_8r2y$9%pbnph*xy*%v^a_!vc0bmbqz%(+l#pc@k7n2r)+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'courses',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

And this is the home.html file

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Well hello there!{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

this is the template file:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="site-container">
            <nav>
                <a href="{% url 'views.hello_world' %}">Home</a>
                <a href="{% url 'courses:list' %}">Courses</a>
            </nav>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the layout.html file

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="site-container">
            <nav>
                <!-- <a href="{% url 'views.hello_world' %}">Home</a> -->
                <a href="{% url 'hello_world' %}">Home</a>
                <a href="{% url 'courses:list' %}">Courses</a>
            </nav>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not able to figure out what the problem is. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to reverse the url for `'views.helloworld'`. But, that's not the name of the url you've defined. That's the view name. Change your `urls.py` file to:

```
url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
```

and then use:

```
<a href="{% url 'hello_world' %}">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the code as follows: from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^courses/', include('courses.urls', namespace='courses')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
    <a href="{% url 'hello_world' %}">Home</a>
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()    But it is giving a syntax error now.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did.. As mentioned in the comment above.But it is not working

Comment: @ledzee That has to go in your html file. Replace the current `href` tag.

Comment: Thanks. This is my layout.html file now {% load static from staticfiles %}

........            <nav>
                <!-- <a href="{% url 'hello_world' %}">Home</a> -->
                <a href="{% url 'hello_world' %}">Home</a>
                <a href="{% url 'courses:list' %}">Courses</a>
            </nav>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html> Its showing the NoReverseMatch error again.

Comment: @ledzee Please post your update files in question. It's difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: @ledzee Are you getting the ReverseMatch error for same url? or `courses:list` url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95965/discussion-between-ledzee-and-rohit-jain).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in the `urls.py` file
Could you try importing the views as
`from courses import views`

Comment: Thanks. But this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

As per Rohits' suggestions above I made the changes and it worked.
Tip: Dont comment out the changes, delete them! Quoting Rohit "Django will try to resolve the {% url %} tags before rendering the HTML page. So, even though you comment that out, it still tries to reverse the url"